# Powershell: filtering event logs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-log

Ive written a small script to retreive event logs from application for the last 10 days but i receive the error.  Any ideas why the error appear?

> Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   value "False" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
>   Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean'  to
>   'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock'."

```
#Sets the application log to query 
$Log ="Application"
$FilterHashTable = @{LogName=$Log}

#stores the computer name 
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 

#sets the date 10 days ago 
$DeleteDate = Get-Date 
$DeleteDate = $DeleteDate.AddDays(-10) 
Write-Verbose $DeleteDate 

#retrieve WMIevent and logs the information 
$Winevent = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable $FilterHashTable  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Filter on time 
$Winevent | where-object ($_.timecreated -gt $DeleteDate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where-Object` needs a scriptblock parameter - use curly braces `{...}` not parentheses `(...)` to contain your filter logic.

Currently PS is checking your criteria and returning a boolean, instead of applying it as a filter.

Comment: Thanks, no matter how much i looked at the where-object i couldnt see the issue.  Thanks. Still one problem left even though $deletedate is 8/04/12, it still showing objects from 26/01/2012

Comment: @resolver101 it's probably a regional setting.  What is your region set to in windows?

Comment: get-culture return 
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2057             en-GB            English (United Kingdom)